# How to register a function in template tags in Django?

Tags: django

I want to keep a function without arguments in template tags in django and to be able to call it in a template.

Example of the function:

```
def my_count():
    return models.MyModel.objects.count()
```

Example of the template:

```
Count: {{ my_count }}
```

How should I define the function `my_count` in my template?

Comment: Check this doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your tags.py:

```
from django import template
from django.conf import settings

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def my_count():
   return models.MyModel.objects.count()
```

Then, in your template:

```
{% my_count %}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You should [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#example) template to view

```
def my_count(request):
    model_count =  models.MyModel.objects.count()
    return render(request, 'myapp/mytemplate.html', {
        'model_count ': model_count,
    })
```

**EDIT**:

You should do the register on your template tag, like in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags)

> ```
> import datetime
> from django import template
>
> register = template.Library()
>
> @register.simple_tag 
> def current_time(format_string):
>     return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(format_string)
> ```

Also template tags are not invoked by

```
{{ my_count }}
```

they are rather invoked using

```
{% my_count %}
```

Comment: I need a template tag, not a view.